# Complation failed when I try to use '@gradio/client' API in an angular-based ionic app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, gradio

When I try to use gradio/client in a simple blank ionic app (angular), compilation fail and return this error message:

```
[ng] node:buffer - Error: Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:buffer" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
[ng] Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
[ng] You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.
[ng]
[ng]
[ng] × Failed to compile.
```

Any suggestion?

I've already tried to downgrade node-fetch as suggested in other answers